# InStr in Recordset.Filter Property

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I have an ADO-Recordset and want to filter it with an Instr Condition. I want to find, whether the short text in the table field can be found in a longer text. If I wanted the other way I could easily use the LIKE operator.

I tried the following code:

```
Dim RS = New ADODB.recordset
RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
RS.Open "SomeTable", SomeConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

RS.Filter = "InStr('SomeLongText', SomeField) > 0"
```

But if I try this, I get the Run-time error 3001:
"Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another."

So, i there a way?

To clarify this: I dont want to find a way what the LIKE operator could do.

NOT: SomeField LIKE Pattern
INSTEAD: Pattern LIKE SomeField

To give an example. I have a table like this:

```
ID Pattern
----------- 
1  AAA
2  BBB
3  CCC
4  DDD
5  EEE
```

Then I want to find for some text like:
"This Text contains a BBB and an EEE." the records where the pattern is in the text. In Code:

```
RS.Filter = "InStr('This Text contains a BBB and an EEE.', Pattern) > 0"
```

will filter for the records with ID 2 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some string in a column you can use this:

```
rs.Filter = "SomeField Like '*SomeLongText*'"
```

You can also filter when you open the recordset in the first place:

```
Dim rs as Recordset
set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField Like '*SomeLongText*'")
```

Comment: Sorry, thats the other way round, end not what I asked for. I know the LIKE operator. I dont want to find a short pattern in a long text field of a DB. Instead of that the short text is in the field and I want to find all records where the content of the field can be found in a long text. I clarified this in the main question text.

Comment: Thats the same way you jus use the search text as variable, like this: `rs.Filter = "'* & rs.Pattern.Value & *'"`